# "virtual A* someMethod" vs "virtual class A* someMethod"

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I've been trying to understand a piece of code that goes like this:

```
class A {
    // some class definition
}

class B {
    public:
        virtual A *someMethod();
        virtual class A *someOtherMethod();
}
```

I can't seem to understand the difference (or if any exists, for that matter) between `someMethod` and `someOtherMethod` - both appear to be virtual methods and both are overridden in classes that inherit from B.

Could someone shed some light on this *virtual class* syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` is the *class name*, and `class A` is the *elaborated type specifier*.
If there's nothing else called `A`, then both refer to the class called `A`.

If there were something else (a function or variable, perhaps) called `A`, then an unqualified use of `A` would refer to that. You'd need the elaborated specifier `class A` to refer to the class. As mentioned in the comments, you can also use `class A` without a previous declaration of the class; the use of the elaborated specifier is enough to introduce the class name into the innermost namespace.

It has little to do with virtual function syntax; both forms can be used to specify the type, whether as the return type of a function or in any other context.

Comment: Also, if there was no previous declaration of `A`, the elaborated type specifier introduces the name `A` into the innermost enclosing namespace scope of the declaration.

Comment: Would this mean that someOtherMethod would, in fact, work as some sort of forward declaration for A (if A was defined after B)?

Comment: @fstanis Yes, but not `someMethod`  if `A` was not previously declared at that point in the program.

Answer (score 1):

In C you used to have to write `struct S` to refer to a structure. In fact there was this pattern to deal with it: `typedef S struct {}`, which creates an unnamed structure, then gives it the name S through type aliasing.

C++ retained this ability, but aliases raw types automatically. In your case, `A` is a type alias to the formal name `class A`. Of course the automatic alias won't work if you have more than one `A`, but that's also a pretty big code smell.

TL;DR: both functions return the same thing. It's a remnant of C for backwards compatibility and extremely frowned upon when used.

Comment: Why the past tense? Has C changed that?

Comment: Well no, C++ changed the need for that. I think of it as an improvement.